# Adding code to a php function with a separate php function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have a php function called `wc_print_notices` that is in the core files of woocommerce, and I don't wish to edit the core files if I can avoid it.

So I would like to write something in my functions.php file that will add more functionality to this function.

I've tried using filters, however, those only work with woocommerce functions that act as hooks, and this is a function that is called through a hook, so `do_action()` and `add_filter` do not work with `wc_print_notices`

I want to add related products to this function, and have tried something like this

```
function popup_products( $popup ){
    $popup = woocommerce_output_related_products();
  return $popup;
}
```

The function itself works perfectly, however, I want to add this to the function `wc_print_notices`

the filters I tried were:

```
add_filter( 'wc_print_notices', 'popup_products', 1, 1);
add_filter( 'wc_print_notices', 'popup_products', 99, 99);
add_filter( 'wc_print_notices', 'popup_products', 1);
add_filter( 'wc_print_notices', 'popup_products', 99);
```

Comment: Did you pass a priority to the `add_filter`? Like `add_filter('the_filter','my_func',10,1)`.

Comment: Sure did :) doesn't work though XD

Comment: Post the code of the attempts you did at overriding the filter,

Comment: Ok, I added them in the main post

Comment: Is the change necessary though because i see that you can use `wc_add_notice` to add additional notices. Or does it really require a major change?

Comment: Also since wc_print_notices is being called by `add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );` i think you will need to remove that action with `remove_action` then `add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'my_custom_wc_print_notices', 10 );`

Comment: Hmm, adding a custom notice would probably work :) can you link the documentation that you saw where to add additional notices?

Answer (score 2):

Since wc_print_notices is being called by `add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );` i think you need to remove that action with `remove_action` then `add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'my_custom_wc_print_notices', 10 );`

> https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_print_notices.html#106-129

Maybe adding additional notices.

> https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_print_notices.html#75-91

I think in your case if all you want to do is add additional information all you have todo is add it in one of the Woocommerce Loop's.

`add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop','popup_products');`

**With OP Clarification**

```
function custom_wc_print_notices() {
if ( ! did_action( 'woocommerce_init' ) ) {
         _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'This function should not be called before woocommerce_init.', 'woocommerce' ), '2.3' );
         return;
     }

     $all_notices  = WC()->session->get( 'wc_notices', array() );
     $notice_types = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_notice_types', array( 'error', 'success', 'notice' ) );

     foreach ( $notice_types as $notice_type ) {
         if ( wc_notice_count( $notice_type ) > 0 ) {
             // Call your function here and make sure it only output once
             woocommerce_output_related_products();
             /********************************************/
             wc_get_template( "notices/{$notice_type}.php", array(
                 'messages' => $all_notices[$notice_type]
             ) );
         }
     }

     wc_clear_notices();
}
```

I think the best bet is like i suggest before to remove the default `add_action` place it back with your modified version of `wc_print_notices`.

Comment: Hmm, this wouldn't be adding to a function, it would just be completely writing a new function.

Comment: Is it possible that all you want is to add aditional information before totally non related to notice?

Comment: Yes, but I only want it to show up when the notice shows up without using javascript.

Comment: Oh i see, that makes more sense now

Comment: I could use javascript with `display:none` and toggle it if the message div exists, however, this would mean that all those elements load unnecessarily  all the time. Which would be inefficient.

Comment: Maybe a AJAX approach could be the answer, it woudn't cost much in performance to check if the message `<div>` exist if it does then get the products and outputting them.

Comment: I agree, I'll probably end up doing that if I can't figure this out. However, the reason I wanted to use php, eventhough it's my weakest language is because I want graceful degradation so that users can use the website with javascript disabled. It's not a pertinent piece of info, just up-selling so it won't be the end of the world with AJAX :) Thanks!